# Return results from money (ruby) with a comparison (e.g. items more than x)

Tags: ruby, currency, money-rails

Pretty simple one.

I want to do the following

```
Model.where("money_rate > ?", some_other_money_item)
```

Any ideas?

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "money_rate" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  WHERE (money_rate > '--- !ruby/...etc
```

Comment: What's your question or problem? It's unclear for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you can only do a comparison using the base method, in the above case this would be money_rate_cents

So:

```
Model.where("money_rate_cents > ?", some_other_money_item_in_cents)
```

Returns an array of items where the money attribute is higher.

Will leave that in case someone else finds it useful. Or in case I'm missing something and you can do comparisons on the whole number.